# Continuous function defined by measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Is the following slightly generalization of Corollary 20.17 in Hewitt and Ross Book (page 296) correct?

Let $A$ be a subset of a profinite group $G$ ( compact, Hausdorff, totally disconnected topological group) such that $A=A^{-1}$ and $\lambda(A)>0$, where $\lambda$ is the normalized Haar measure of $G$. Suppose that 
$f$ is the function defined on $G\times \cdots \times G$ ($k$ times) into $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$  by $$(x_1,\dots,x_k)\mapsto \lambda(A\cap x_1 A \cap \cdots \cap x_k A).$$
Then $f$ is continuous.

Note that  $f(1,\dots,1)=\lambda(A)$ ( $1$ is the identity element of $G$), so $f$ is somewhere
positive.

Comment: I bet it is: if $x_{j,n}$ converges to $x_j$, then $\mathbb{1}_{x_{j,n}A}$ converges a.e. to $\mathbb{1}_{x_jA}$, and thus $\mathbb{1}_{A \cap x_{1,n}A \cap \ldots \cap x_{k,n}A}$ converges a.e. to $\mathbb{1}_{A \cap x_{1}A \cap \ldots \cap x_{k}A}$. The desired result follows now by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: I think your first claim will be true if $A$ is open, am I right?

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan: I meant general Borel $A$, but I was indeed too sketchy when I wrote "converges a.e. to $\mathbb{1}_{x_jA}$": what I should have written is "converges in measure to $\mathbb{1}_{x_jA}$, and hence every subsequence has a sub-subsequence convergent a.e.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the assumption of profiniteness is not needed (see comments). This can be proved by approximating in $L^2$
 the indicator function $1_A$ by a continuous function $f$.

Using the fact that such $f$ must be uniformly continuous, any small perturbation $f_g$ of $f$ is within a small $L^\infty$ error of $f$. Therefore the map
$$\Phi_f:(x_1,\dots,x_k)\mapsto\int_G f(g)f(x_1^{-1}g)\cdots f(x_k^{-1}g)\,d\lambda(g)$$
is continuous.

As $f\to1_A$ in $L^2$, Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality (together with the fact that we can keep every function in this argument bounded by $2$) implies that $\Phi_f\to\Phi_{1_A}$ uniformly, which shows that $\Phi_{1_A}$ is also continuous.
Finally, note that
$$\Phi_{1_A}(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\lambda(A\cap x_1A\cap\cdots\cap x_kA).$$

The more general principle at play here is that for any $p<\infty$ the map $g\mapsto f_g$ from $G$ to $L^p(G)$ is continuous, where $f_g$ denotes the function $f_g(x)=f(gx)$.

Comment: I guess "*assumption of profiniteness is not needed*" has to be interpreted as: being, instead, locally compact ($\sigma$-compact?) is enough.

Comment: @YCor I was thinking of compact Hausdorff (I should have said totally disconnected is not needed) but now that you mention it I think locally compact should be enough. All that's needed is existence of Haar measure and denseness in $L^2$ of compactly supported continuous functions.

Comment: But you deduce uniform continuity of $f$ from continuity of $f$, so surely need compactness?  (EDIT:  Oops, sorry, I just saw 'compactly supported'.)